# Instagram Scraping within a specified time period?

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, instagram

I'm trying to extract information from various social media pages for the county I work for. Need information for all posts in the last year (primarily date posted, reach, likes). Does anyone have source code or an API that I may be able to use?

I tried using instaloader, but was not able to extract the reach. any way I can just put all data in a CSV or xlsx would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I remember by Instagram settings, privacy or security section, you can request sending a backup link to your Email. Other way, maybe using Selenium is what you want.